# Plotting in Python via matplotlib.pyplot (calculate the area)

Tags: python, python-2.7, graph, matplotlib, plot

I have a question \ problem. I need to plot the graph by the numbers that I got from the file (which I did) and then I need to draw a line connecting start and end, and calculate the area that between these two lines. I try to make a lot of variations, but i have no idea how I can make it..

I'm trying do it via matplotlib.pyplot library

[image]

Here the 'figure' whitch I should to get after add 'connection line between beginning and and' and now I need calcutale square between black line and blue. 
PS the black one is kind of straight :)

[image]

Here is soure of code, and my data file... 
http://pastebin.com/g40bAzPR

```
#!/path/to/python -tt

# numerical data
# python GraphicalPart.py ../dataFile.txt

import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def startDivide(fileName):
 for i in range(1,2):
    inputFile = open(fileName)
    outputFile = open(fileName + "_" + str(i) + "_out.csv", "w")
    floatList = []
    for line in inputFile.readlines():
        data = line.split(" ")
        string = data[i]
        if string.startswith('-'): #remove '-'
            string = string[1:]
        floatList.append(float(string))

    floatList.sort() #sorting the list of data

    for item in floatList:
        outputFile.write("%s\n" % item)

    outputFile.close() 
    inputFile.close()

    data1=np.genfromtxt(fileName + "_" + str(i) + '_out.csv', skip_header=1)
    plt.plot(data1) 
    plt.savefig(fileName + "_" + str(i) + "_.png")
    plt.clf()

def main():
 if len(sys.argv) != 2:
  print "Not enough arguments. *_data.txt file only!"
 else:
  startDivide(sys.argv[1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
 main()
```

Comment: I mean, calculate square of 'figure' which is obtained after the line between the beginning and the end

Comment: Added more details to post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for i in range(1,2)` is a loop which only iterates once. Maybe you plan on increasing the number of iterations? If so, bear in mind that it's quicker to load the data *once*, rather than multiple times in a for-loop.  You can do that using `np.genfromtxt` with the `usecols` parameter to specify the desired columns.

To find the area under the curve, you could use
[np.trapz](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html).
To find the area between two curves, you subtract area under the upper curve from the area under the lower curve. Assuming the diagonal line is always above the data curve:

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def startDivide(filename):
    data = np.genfromtxt(filename, dtype=None, usecols=[1])
    data = np.abs(data)
    data.sort()
    np.savetxt("{}_1_out.csv".format(filename), data)
    plt.plot(data)
    plt.plot([0,len(data)-1], [data[0], data[-1]])
    plt.savefig("{}_1_.png".format(filename))
    area = np.trapz([data[0], data[-1]], dx=len(data)-1) - np.trapz(data)
    print(area)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    startDivide(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, about ***for i in range(1,2)***, This is for test, in future here I will use for whole colums (1,8).. And yes, your code looks better than mine :) but I got an error for 'filename' like "NameError: global name 'filename' is not define..." :\

Comment: I tried you plot line and counting area on my code - it's work good! thanks a lot. Could you please vote for my topic, I need more score :) thanks